# How to mix textures in DirectX?

Tags: directx, textures

I am new to DirectX development and I am wondering if I am taking the wrong route to achieve the following:

I would like to mix three textures which contain transparent areas and some solid areas (Red, Blue, Green). The three textures should blend like shown in this example:

[image]

How can I achieve that in DirectX (preferably in directx9)?

A link or example code would be nice.

**Update:**

My rendering method looks like this and I still think I am doing it wrong, because the sprite only shows the last texture (nothing is rendered transparent or blended):

```
void D3DTester::render()
{
d3ddevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0), 1.0f, 0);
d3ddevice->BeginScene();

d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);

LPD3DXSPRITE sprite=NULL;
HRESULT hres = D3DXCreateSprite(d3ddevice, &sprite);
if(hres != S_OK)
{
    throw std::exception(); 
}

sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

std::vector<LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9>::iterator it;
for ( it=textures.begin() ; it < textures.end(); it++ )
{
    sprite->Draw(*it, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

sprite->End();

d3ddevice->EndScene();
d3ddevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

The resulting image looks like this:

[image]

But I need it to look like this instead:

[image]

**Update2:**
I figured out that I have to `SetRenderState` after I use `sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);` thanks to the hint by Josh Petrie. However, by using this:

```
    sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);

std::vector<LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9>::iterator it;
for ( it=textures.begin() ; it < textures.end(); it++ )
{   
    sprite->Draw(*it, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
sprite->End();
```

The sprites colors are becoming transparent towards the background scene e.g.:
if I use `d3ddevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,100,21), 1.0f, 0);` the result looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid that?
I would like the sprites be transparent to each other but to be still solid to the background.

**Update3:**
After having sombody explained to me, how to do what @LaurentCouvidou and @JoshPetrie suggested, I have a working solution and therfore accept the answer:

```
d3ddevice->BeginScene();

D3DCOLOR white = D3DCOLOR_RGBA((UINT)255, (UINT)255, (UINT)255, 255);
D3DCOLOR black = D3DCOLOR_RGBA((UINT)0, (UINT)0, (UINT)0, 255);

sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
sprite->Draw(pTextureRed, NULL, NULL, NULL, black);
sprite->Draw(pTextureGreen, NULL, NULL, NULL, black);
sprite->Draw(pTextureBlue, NULL, NULL, NULL, black);
sprite->End();       


sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, TRUE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_BLENDOP, D3DBLENDOP_ADD);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
sprite->Draw(pTextureRed, NULL, NULL, NULL, white);
sprite->Draw(pTextureGreen, NULL, NULL, NULL, white);
sprite->Draw(pTextureBlue, NULL, NULL, NULL, white);
sprite->End();

d3ddevice->EndScene();
d3ddevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

*Update: 
since this question is rather popular, I'd like to point out [a website](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) where you can experiment with opengl blendmodes:*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID3DXSprite interface will modify the render states of the device when you call the `Begin` method. The specifics of the state modifications that will be performed are detailed in [the method's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular, note that the source and destination blend modes are set to 'source alpha' and 'inverse source alpha,' respectively. This enables the typical blending behavior wherein the alpha component of the color is used to control how transparent a pixel is.

Since this isn't what you want, you should pass the `D3DXSPRITE_DONOTMODIFY_RENDERSTATE` flag to `Begin` and ensure, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notes, that

> The device is assumed to be in a valid state to draw vertices
>   containing `UsageIndex = 0` in the `D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION`,
>   `D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD`, and `D3DDECLUSAGE_COLOR` data.

By doing this, the render states you set up to blend the way you want will be preserved. You may note that doing this changes some other aspect of your render behavior, and that is probably due to your not setting other render states to the values described in the documentation for `Begin`.

As an aside, you shouldn't test `HRESULT` values against specific constants (like `S_OK`) if all you want to know is success or failure -- as is the case in your code. There are multiple success or failure codes. Prefer the [SUCCEEDED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FAILED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to those SUCCEEDED/FAILED marcos (+1 for that) I will try out your suggestion and have a look into the docs first.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but now the three sprites are not only transparent towards each other but also transparent in regards to the "background scene". Any idea how to avoid that and to have the output as shown in the first picture?

Comment: That's, uh, weird looking. I'm not sure how you get that greenish hue for the background -- are you rendering fullscreen quads for all of these? Could you update/post more of your code?

Comment: The greenish hue is because of the line `3ddevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,100,21), 1.0f, 0);` I put there to emphasize the problem. I am not quite sure what "fullscreen quads" are but I doubt that I am rendering those. I am just taking the `D3DXCreateSprite`s and let them draw `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9`s. Maybe what I want to achieve isn't even possible and I have to come up with a different solution.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in one pass, you'll have to render your 3 sprites first as complete black, and then re-render using additive blending.

Comment: Ah, I see, yes, I missed that your background was no longer a solid black. Because you are blending additively your sprites will add their color to the background color already present in the frame buffer, so a two-pass solution as lorancou describes should solve it.

Comment: Thanks lorancou and @Josh Petrie! I think I understood but I still don't know how to achieve that (e.g. how to render 3 sprites first without the background and then add it to the scene keeping the rendered sprites solid). Maybe you can help me by adjusting the sample code? Thanks your guys for helping me!

Comment: I figured it out after sombody showed me how to do it. Thanks @LaurentCouvidou and Josh

Answer (score 1):

This is known as *Additive Blending*.

In DirectX9, you use a few render states to set that up:

```
pDirect3DDevice9->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
pDirect3DDevice9->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
pDirect3DDevice9->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
```

Comment: I updated the question showing the sample code.